# Titanium.Contacts.showContacts , alphabetically first name

Tags: iphone, titanium-mobile

I am using Titanium to develop a mobile app. I have stuck in a problem, where i want to show contact list. I used the following code to show contact list

```
Titanium.Contacts.showContacts({ });
```

I am getting the contact list, but it shows in sorting order of last name . I want the list to be shown in sorting order of first name.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a property Ti.Contacts.CONTACTS_SORT_FIRST_NAME hope this helps. There is also CONTACTS_KIND_ORGANIZATION, and CONTACTS_KIND_PERSON.

```
var g = Ti.Contacts.getAllGroups( );//Getting all the groups on the contacts table

var m = g[0].members();//select a group and check if it has members
Ti.API.info(m)// my group was empty so i have to add people

var p = Ti.Contacts.getAllPeople( )// get all the contacts
for (var i in p){//group and add people to your group
    g[0].add(p[i]);
    Ti.API.info(p[i].firstName);
    Titanium.Contacts.save()// you have to save new changes in IOS
}
g[0].sortedMembers(Ti.Contacts.CONTACTS_SORT_FIRST_NAME);// FINALLY WE CAN SORT

m = g[0].members();//   get the members 

for (var i in m){// verify they are in order
    Ti.API.info(m[i].firstName);
}
```